# Entity Framework Entity Information from the Table Name (for auditing)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In Entity Framework (for .NET Core) it is possible to get entity and property information from the object type, for example `DB.Model.FindEntityType(curObj.GetType()).GetProperties()`, and then a call like `property.SqlServer()` can give you the mapped property information.

Is it possible to start with the table name instead of the entity type? For example, suppose I know the table is called `EMPLOYEE`, is there a way to ask Entity Framework to give me the entity mapped to this table name?

Why do I want to do this?

I know this is not the standard way of working with Entity Framework, but we have a database audit system that we now want to show to users, so we need to somewhat manually map database data to code.

Comment: I wish I had a manual to work with all the meta data that entity framework creates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this directly.

What I did instead was to scan the assembly and namespace where my entities are located, and populate my own structure by manually looping through each entity.

```
        // null checks removed for demonstration
        var asm = Assembly.Load(myEntityAssembly);
        var classes = asm.GetTypes().Where(p => p.Namespace?.StartsWith(myEntityNamespace) == true).ToList();

        foreach (var type in classes)
        {
            var entityType = DB.Model.FindEntityType(type);
            var tableName = entityType.SqlServer().TableName.ToUpper();
            // ...
        }
```